# ASP.NET validation controls on error event?

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation

I am using asp.net validation controls. Please guide is it possible to catch OnError (or the event on which validation control is fired and then as a result message is shown) ? I want to do some custom UI effects  on this event.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use CustomValidator to perform your own validation logic
- Inherit from [any of built-in validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx), override [EvaluateIsValid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.evaluateisvalid.aspx), call base method, react, and return.

Comment: I donot mean custom logic, I want to do custom UI effects. Please guide.

Comment: @user576510: In most cases you can go with 2nd way, and get you want. What sort of effect do you want? Please elaborate

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to display that a validation failed you can use the ValidationSummary Control.